# Workflow Foundation - Terminate vs Abort vs Cancel

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I'm using WorkflowFoundation 4.0 in WinForms application. When the user closes the form, the program doesn't exit because the workflow is running in background.

The workflow is created like this:

```
WorkflowApplication workflow = new WorkflowApplication(new myActivity());
workflow.Run();
```

I'd like to 'close' it in my FormClosing event. Which method should I use? `Terminate`, `Abort` or `Cancel`?

Comment: What do you mean by 'close' it. what exactly you want to do with the workflow.

Comment: I'd like to abort it's thread so the form is disposed fully, and not to have leftover threads running...

Comment: what i understand is that when you close the form you want to abort the workflow and do not continue it again any more, am i right?

Comment: @Ghyath - yes, that's right. Just a simple scenario..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on your needs/workflow either Terminate or Cancel. Abort is designed to leave the persisted state around, if you are using the instance store, and restart the workflow from the last saved state.

Use terminate if you want no more activities, including cleanup like Finally blocks, to execute. Use Cancel if you want to have the capability to have the workflow cleanup after itself. I would suggest Cancel in most cases.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 5):

There is a thorough answer here:

- [Windows workflow 4 : difference between WorkflowApplication Cancel, Terminate and Abort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281891/windows-workflow-4-difference-between-workflowapplication-cancel-terminate-and)